# Laravel Append Search Results to Pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pagination

I have managed to get close to create pagination for my AJAX filters. The only thing is that it resets after I click on a link. I need a way for the pagination to remember the search that was previous applied. I am able to get the correct amount of pages displayed with the search. The only problem with it is that it resets when I click on the pagination link.

Code I am using:

*Blade:*

```
@foreach($launchsitesatellite as $satellite)
<div id="main-data">
    <div class="table-row" id="launchsatdisplay">
        {{$satellite->satname}}
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
{{$launchsitesatellite->links()}}
```

*AJAX Call for Pagination:*

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){
    page = window.location.hash.replace('#','');
    getObjects(page);
});
$(document).on('click','.pagination a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).attr('href').split('page=')[1];
    location.hash = page;
});
function getObjects(page){
    $('#default').remove();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/data/{{$launchsitename->site_code}}?page=' + page
    }).done(function(data){
        $('#data-holder').html(data);
    });
};
```

*PHP Function:*

```
public function ajax(Request $request, $site_code)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
            ->where(function ($q) use ($request) {
                if (empty($request->type)) {
                    $q->where('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->country . '%');
                } else {
                    $q->Where('object_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%');
                };
            })
            ->where('site', $site_code)
            ->Paginate(40);
    } else {
        $launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('site', $site_code)->Paginate(40);
    }
    return View::make('partials.launchsitedata')->with('launchsitesatellite', $launchsitesatellite)->render();
}
```

*AJAX Search/Filter:*

```
$("#apply").click(function() {
$country=$('#filter-country').val();
$type=$('#filter-type').val();
$year=$('#filter-year').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/data/{{$launchsitename->site_code}}",
        data: {'country':$country, 'object_type':$type, 'launch':$year},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#data-holder').html(data);
    });
});
```

**TL;DR** How would you prevent pagination resetting my AJAX search/filters when I go to page 2, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client you will need to load the query parameter filter values on load of document.

eg: (no error checking)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Populate filters from query parameters
  $('#filter-type').val(GetURLParameter('type'));
  ....
```

Then on the server you will need to append your query filters to the links code

eg in the code before you render the blade template

```
if(isset($typeFilter)){ 
  $launchsitesatellite->appends(['type' => typeFilter])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! So would this go in my AJAX call for the pagination or the actual filters?

Comment: This would be some separate code that is there to keep your filters in sync between page refreshes.

Comment: I have updated the answer to give a better idea of where the code would live.

Comment: Would I then have to do something with the AJAX call itself to send those values?

Comment: You would not need to change your ajax, or server code.

The changes above will save the filter values to localStorage everytime they are modified, and when the page loads initially it will read the values in from local Storage.

there are 2 possible issues that might come up depending on the rest of your code

1. Do you always load the list using ajax, or do you actual server render it on first page display?
2. If you do load it by ajax on page load, you need to load it after the fitlers are updated from localStorage

Comment: Just tried your code - unfortunately the pagination still resets the filters. I think it is just not remembering the filters or the values in your code. I will see what I can do right now. The page that I choose has the filter values reset.

Comment: I first load the page using normal pagination. The server renders it on first page display. Then whenever a user selects a page number it uses AJAX to get that paginated page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156788/discussion-between-chris-phillips-and-d-777klm).